# How to setup openvpn client on linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, nautilus, openvpn

I am used to setting up the openvpn clinet on windows 7. How do I setup openvpn clinet on linux mint? I can't find a gui or a simple way to do so.

My gui is **nautilus**

Answer (score 1):

You can install the openVpn Manager and do it from there i believe

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

You should get the  openvpn option in the network-manager GUI menu

Comment: euxaresto fili, Kalo ta vradi

Comment: will that work with nautilus?

Comment: How do I open the gui on LinuxMint/Cinnamon?

Comment: You should see the vpn settings in the Network Manager. click on the small picture on the left to see the menu.  http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/network-manager-gnome